# Conditional custom checkout fields based on product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I am using woocommerce for a site for a nonprofit that sells tickets to classes and tickets to events. When someone is signing up for a class then need to list their emergency contact information and agree to a liability release. When they are buying a ticket to an event the nonprofit doesn't need the emergency contact info or the liability release. So... they want those fields to appear on the woocommerce checkout only on the condition that the person is checking out with a ticket for a class.  Make sense?

I figured out how to add the custom fields and the custom liability releases a few months ago when they first added the classes to the website. I created a "class" product category in woocommerce and a function to test for any products in the shopping cart that are in that category, so I can conditionally show the fields.

All of these functions are in my functions.php file and I right now I am running the conditional statement to check for the "class" category in each of the functions. I need help learning how to check for the "class" category once, then run the functions that display the fields, validated the fields, add the data to the database and generate the new order emails. Make sense?

Here's what I have currently:

```
// Add fields for Emergency Contact & Medical Information to the checkout page
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'customise_checkout_field');

function customise_checkout_field($checkout)
{

    // Check to see if there is a class in the cart
    // function is at the end
    $class_in_cart = is_conditional_product_in_cart( 'class' );

    // There is a class in the cart so show additional fields
    if ( $class_in_cart === true ) {

    echo '<div id="customise_checkout_field"><h3>' . __('Emergency Contact & Medical Information') . '</h3>';
    woocommerce_form_field('emergency_contact', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array(
            'emergency-contact form-row-wide'
        ) ,
        'label' => __('Emergency Contact') ,
        'placeholder' => __('Please enter first & last name') ,
        'required' => true,
    ) , $checkout->get_value('emergency_contact'));
    woocommerce_form_field('emergency_contact_relationship', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array(
            'emergency-contact-relationship form-row-wide'
        ) ,
        'label' => __('What is your relationship with this person?') ,
        'placeholder' => __('Example: Mother') ,
        'required' => true,
    ) , $checkout->get_value('emergency_contact_relationship'));
    woocommerce_form_field('emergency_contact_phone', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array(
            'emergency-contact-phone form-row-wide'
        ) ,
        'label' => __('What is their phone number?') ,
        'placeholder' => __('(555) 555-5555') ,
        'required' => true,
    ) , $checkout->get_value('emergency_contact_phone'));
    woocommerce_form_field('medical_medicine', array(
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'class' => array(
            'medical-medicine form-row-wide'
        ) ,
        'label' => __('Do you have any medical conditions and are you taking any medications we need to be aware of?') ,
        'placeholder' => __('If not please write in "none"') ,
        'required' => true,
    ) , $checkout->get_value('medical_medicine'));
    echo '</div>';
    }
}

// Process emergency contact fields

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_fields_process');

function custom_checkout_fields_process() {
    // Check to see if there is a class in the cart
    $class_in_cart = is_conditional_product_in_cart( 'class' );

    // There is a class in the cart so show additional fields
    if ( $class_in_cart === true ) {

        // if the field is set, if not then show an error message.
        if (!$_POST['emergency_contact']) wc_add_notice(__('Please list an emergency contact.') , 'error');
        if (!$_POST['emergency_contact_relationship']) wc_add_notice(__('Please indicate your relationship with your emergency contact.') , 'error');
        if (!$_POST['emergency_contact_phone']) wc_add_notice(__('Please list a phone number for your emergency contact.') , 'error');
        if (!$_POST['medical_medicine']) wc_add_notice(__('Please list any medications or write in "none".') , 'error');
    }
}

// Add emergency contact information to the database

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_fields_update_order_meta');

function custom_checkout_fields_update_order_meta($order_id) {
    // Check to see if there is a class in the cart
    $class_in_cart = is_conditional_product_in_cart( 'class' );

    // There is a class in the cart so show additional fields
    if ( $class_in_cart === true ) {
        if (!empty($_POST['emergency_contact'])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'emergency_contact', sanitize_text_field($_POST['emergency_contact']));
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['emergency_contact_relationship'])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'emergency_contact_relationship', sanitize_text_field($_POST['emergency_contact_relationship']));
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['emergency_contact_phone'])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'emergency_contact_phone', sanitize_text_field($_POST['emergency_contact_phone']));
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['medical_medicine'])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'medical_medicine', sanitize_text_field($_POST['medical_medicine']));
        }
    }
}

// Add the emergency contact fields to order email

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys' );
function my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    // Check to see if there is a class in the cart
    $class_in_cart = is_conditional_product_in_cart( 'class' );

    // There is a class in the cart so show additional fields
    if ( $class_in_cart === true ) {
        echo '<h2>Emergency Contact & Medical Information:</h2>';
        $keys['Emergency Contact'] = 'emergency_contact';
        $keys['Emergency Contact Relationship'] = 'emergency_contact_relationship';
        $keys['Emergency Contact Phone'] = 'emergency_contact_phone';
        $keys['Medical Conditions & Medications'] = 'medical_medicine';
        return $keys;
    } // end class in cart condition
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Add custom checkboxes to woocommerce checkout page for Photo Release, Mailing List & Release of Liability
// add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_fields' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'custom_checkout_fields' );
function custom_checkout_fields() {
    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_fields">
    <h3>Mailing Lists</h3>
    <p>Mailing List boilerplate';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'mailing_consent', array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'class'     => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'     => __('Please add me to Nonprofit\'s electronic and paper mailing lists.'),
        'required'  => false,
        'clear'     => true,
        'default'   => 1 //This will pre-select the checkbox
    ),  WC()->checkout->get_value( 'mailing_consent' ) );

    // Check to see if there is a class in the cart
    $class_in_cart = is_conditional_product_in_cart( 'class' );

    // There is a class in the cart so show additional fields
    if ( $class_in_cart === true ) {

        echo '<h3>Photo Release</h3>
        <p>Photo Release Boilerplate</p>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'photo_consent', array(
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'class'     => array('input-checkbox'),
            'label'     => __('I agree to the Photo Release as outlined above.'),
            'required'  => false,
            'clear'     => true,
            'default'   => 1 //This will pre-select the checkbox
        ),  WC()->checkout->get_value( 'photo_consent' ) );

        echo '<h3>Release of Liability</h3>
        <p>Release of Liability Boilerplate</p>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'liability_release', array(
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'class'     => array('input-checkbox'),
            'label'     => __('I agree to the Photo Release as outlined above.'),
            'required'  => true,
            'clear'     => true,
            'default'   => 1 //This will pre-select the checkbox
        ),  WC()->checkout->get_value( 'liability_release' ) );

    } // end class in cart condition

    echo '</div>';
}

// Show notice if customer doesn't check the Release of Liability checkbox
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'liability_release_not_given' );

function liability_release_not_given() {
    // Check to see if there is a class in the cart
    $class_in_cart = is_conditional_product_in_cart( 'class' );

    // There is a class in the cart so show additional fields
    if ( $class_in_cart === true ) {
        if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['liability_release'] ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'You must agree to the Release of Liability to register for this class.  Please contact us with any questions.' ), 'error' );
        }
    } // end class in cart condition
}

// Save the custom checkout field in the order meta, when checkbox has been checked
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['mailing_consent'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'mailing_consent', $_POST['mailing_consent'] );

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['photo_consent'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'photo_consent', $_POST['photo_consent'] );

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['liability_release'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'liability_release', $_POST['liability_release'] );
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Display custom field results on the order edit page (backend)
// for various liability fields

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages( $order ){

    $mailing_consent = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'mailing_consent', true );
    if( $mailing_consent == 1 )
        echo '<p>' . $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name . ' agreed to the be added to Nonprofit\'s mailing lists.</p>';

    $photo_consent = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'photo_consent', true );
    if( $photo_consent == 1 )
        echo '<p>' . $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name . ' agreed to the Photo Release.</p>';

    $liability_release = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'liability_release', true );
    if( $liability_release == 1 )
        echo '<p>' . $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name . ' agreed to the Release of Liability.</p>';
}


/**
 * Check if Class is In cart
 *
 * https://wordimpress.com/create-conditional-checkout-fields-woocommerce/
 * https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-check-product-category-cart/
 *
 * @param $product_id
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_conditional_product_in_cart( $category_name ) {
    //Check to see if user has a class in their cart
    global $woocommerce;

    //flag no class in cart
    $class_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

    //  if ( $_product->cat === $category_id ) {
        //  //class is in cart!
            //$class_in_cart = true;

        if (has_term ( $category_name, 'product_cat', $_product->get_id() ) ) {
            //class is in cart!
            $class_in_cart = true;
        }
    }

    return $class_in_cart;

}
```

As you can probably tell I pieced this together from various sources on the web and I realize it is a bit of a mess. Currently the conditional statement:

```
// Check to see if there is a class in the cart
$class_in_cart = is_conditional_product_in_cart( 'class' );

// There is a class in the cart so show additional fields
if ( $class_in_cart === true ) {
```

Is repeated for each function. I know this isn't efficient but I'm not sure how to fix it. What I would like to do is this:

1. Test for products that are in the "class" category
2. If "class" then run all the functions to display and process emergency contact fields and photo release and release of liability fields
3. Display "join mailing list" agreement regardless of whether or not there is a "class" in the cart and process that field no matter what.

I tried just wrapping everything in another function but that broke the code. Maybe it would be best to move this into a plugin?

Thanks for any ideas and help you can give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the conditional function code that you are using is really old, outdated and **will not work** when cart items are product variations *(so for variable products)*. Here below is the compact and working conditional function… 
It can work with any product category term ID, slug, name or an array of values:

```
function is_product_cat_in_cart( $categories ) {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if (has_term ( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now the rest of your code has a lot of mistakes or little errors.

It also use outdated or deprecated hooks like:

- `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` replaced by a much appropriated hook.
- `woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys` is deprecated since a lot of time.

You can also merge some code together in the same hooked functions.

You don't need the conditional function everywhere. It's just needed for checkout fields conditional display.

Here is your revisited code *(for woocommerce version 3 and above)*:

```
// Add fields for Emergency Contact & Medical Information to the checkout page
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'customise_checkout_field', 20, 1 );
function customise_checkout_field( $checkout ){
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    // There is a class in the cart so show additional fields
    if ( is_product_cat_in_cart( 'class' ) ):

    echo '<div id="customise_checkout_field">
    <h3>' . __( 'Emergency Contact & Medical Information', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'emergency_contact', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( 'emergency-contact form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Emergency Contact', $domain ) ,
        'placeholder'   => __( 'Please enter first & last name', $domain ),
        'required'      => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value('emergency_contact') );

    woocommerce_form_field( 'emergency_contact_relationship', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( 'emergency-contact-relationship form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'What is your relationship with this person?', $domain ),
        'placeholder'   => __( 'Example: Mother', $domain ) ,
        'required'      => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value('emergency_contact_relationship') );

    woocommerce_form_field( 'emergency_contact_phone', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( 'emergency-contact-phone form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'What is their phone number?', $domain ),
        'placeholder'   => __( '(555) 555-5555', $domain ),
        'required'      => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value('emergency_contact_phone') );

    woocommerce_form_field( 'medical_medicine', array(
        'type'          => 'textarea',
        'class'         => array( 'medical-medicine form-row-wide' ) ,
        'label'         => __( 'Do you have any medical conditions and are you taking any medications we need to be aware of?', $domain ),
        'placeholder'   => __( 'If not please write in "none"', $domain ),
        'required'      => true,
    ) , $checkout->get_value('medical_medicine') );
    echo '</div>';

    endif;
}

// Add custom checkboxes to woocommerce checkout page for Photo Release, Mailing List & Release of Liability
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'custom_checkout_fields' );
function custom_checkout_fields() {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;
    $domain   = 'woocommerce';

    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_fields">
    <h3>'.__( 'Mailing Lists', $domain ).'</h3>
    <p>'.__( 'Mailing List boilerplate', $domain ).'</p>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'mailing_consent', array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'class'     => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'     => __( 'Please add me to Nonprofit\'s electronic and paper mailing lists.', $domain ),
        'required'  => false,
        'clear'     => true,
        'default'   => 1 //This will pre-select the checkbox
    ),  $checkout->get_value( 'mailing_consent' ) );

    // There is a class in the cart so show additional fields
    if ( is_product_cat_in_cart( 'class' ) ):

    echo '<h3>'.__( 'Photo Release', $domain ).'</h3>
    <p>'.__( 'Photo Release Boilerplate', $domain ).'</p>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'photo_consent', array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'class'     => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'     => __( 'I agree to the Photo Release as outlined above.', $domain ),
        'required'  => false,
        'clear'     => true,
        'default'   => 1 //This will pre-select the checkbox
    ),  $checkout->get_value( 'photo_consent' ) );

    echo '<h3>'.__( 'Release of Liability', $domain ).'</h3>
    <p>'.__( 'Release of Liability Boilerplate', $domain ).'</p>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'liability_release', array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'class'     => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'     => __( 'I agree to the Photo Release as outlined above.', $domain ),
        'required'  => true,
        'clear'     => true,
        'default'   => 1 //This will pre-select the checkbox
    ),  $checkout->get_value( 'liability_release' ) );

    endif;

    echo '</div>';
}

// Custom checkout fields validation
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_fields_process');
function custom_checkout_fields_process() {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    if ( isset($_POST['emergency_contact']) && empty($_POST['emergency_contact']) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please list an emergency contact.', $domain ) , 'error' );

    if ( isset($_POST['emergency_contact_relationship']) && empty($_POST['emergency_contact']) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please indicate your relationship with your emergency contact.', $domain ), 'error' );

    if ( isset($_POST['emergency_contact_phone']) && empty($_POST['emergency_contact']) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please list a phone number for your emergency contact.', $domain ), 'error' );

    if ( isset($_POST['medical_medicine']) && empty($_POST['emergency_contact']) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please list any medications or write in "none".', $domain ), 'error' );

    // Other checkout fields
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['liability_release'] ) && ! $_POST['liability_release'] && isset($_POST['photo_consent']) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You must agree to the Release of Liability to register for this class.  Please contact us with any questions.', $domain ), 'error' );
}

// Save custom checkout fields in the order meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'custom_checkout_fields_in_order_meta_data', 20, 2 );
function custom_checkout_fields_in_order_meta_data( $order, $data ) {

    if ( isset($_POST['emergency_contact']) && ! empty($_POST['emergency_contact']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( 'emergency_contact', sanitize_text_field($_POST['emergency_contact']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['emergency_contact_relationship']) && ! empty($_POST['emergency_contact_relationship']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( 'emergency_contact_relationship', sanitize_text_field($_POST['emergency_contact_relationship']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['emergency_contact_phone']) && ! empty($_POST['emergency_contact_phone']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( 'emergency_contact_phone', sanitize_text_field($_POST['emergency_contact_phone']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['medical_medicine']) && ! empty($_POST['medical_medicine']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( 'medical_medicine', sanitize_text_field($_POST['medical_medicine']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['mailing_consent']) && ! empty($_POST['mailing_consent']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( 'mailing_consent', '1' );

    if ( isset( $_POST['photo_consent']) && ! empty($_POST['photo_consent']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( 'photo_consent', '1' );

    if ( isset( $_POST['liability_release']) && ! empty($_POST['liability_release']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( 'liability_release', '1' );
}

// Add the emergency contact fields to email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_checkout_field_email_order_meta', 20, 3 );
function custom_checkout_field_email_order_meta( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    if( ! $order->get_meta( 'emergency_contact' ) )
        return $fields; // Exit if not set in the order

    echo '<h2>'.__( 'Emergency Contact & Medical Information', $domain ).'</h2>';

    $fields[] = array( 'label' => __( 'Emergency contact', $domain ),
        'value' => $order->get_meta( 'emergency_contact' ) );

    $fields[] = array( 'label' => __( 'Emergency Contact Relationship', $domain ),
        'value' => $order->get_meta( 'emergency_contact_relationship' ) );

    $fields[] = array( 'label' => __( 'Emergency Contact Phone', $domain ),
        'value' => $order->get_meta( 'emergency_contact_phone' ) );

    $fields[] = array( 'label' => __( 'Medical Conditions & Medications', $domain ),
        'value' => $order->get_meta( 'medical_medicine' ) );

    return $fields;
}

// Display some custom checkout fields in Order edit pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages', 20, 1 );
function display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages( $order ){
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    $billing_name = $order->get_billing_first_name().' '.$order->get_billing_last_name();

    if( $order->get_meta('mailing_consent') )
        echo '<p>' . $billing_name . __( ' agreed to the be added to Nonprofit\'s mailing lists.', $domain ).'</p>';

    if( $order->get_meta('photo_consent') )
        echo '<p>' . $billing_name . __( ' agreed to the Photo Release.', $domain ).'</p>';

    if( $order->get_meta('liability_release') )
        echo '<p>' . $billing_name . __( ' agreed to the Release of Liability.', $domain ).'</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Conclusion: If some code doesn't work in function.php file, it will not work better in a plugin. But if you want you can add it in a plugin, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick and thorough reply, and thanks for taking the time to rework the code I posted, I was just hoping for a few pointers! I think should've joined stackoverflow and asked for help a long time ago, I have a feeling it would have save me from many hours of banging my head against the wall. I'm looking forward to comparing the code this week so I can learn from your changes.

Comment: What's the best way to pass the custom information to the new order email template? I created a custom template for that email, but I'd rather do it through the function.php if possible....